# How to copy/paste conditional formatting from one Google spreadsheet document to another one?

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste, gs-conditional-formatting

I was wondering how to copy/paste conditional formatting across documents -- not spreadsheets within a document, but between two different docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same conditional formatting in two different documents there is good news for you, you have a choice:

1. Copy the entire document, or
2. recreate the CF in the second document.

I'm afraid the bad news is that neither is exactly *convenient*.

*Edit:* I admit I was expecting the “start again” option to be the preferred one – hence the above ‘non’ (French) answer was mainly intended to not leave a Q without an A. However, if the rules are complex enough and/or there are enough of them it seems a rather convoluted approach may be better than recreating all the rules from scratch. The rigmarole was described well in a Comment from OP, an excerpt from which is repeated here:

> Copied the document with the conditional formatting rules, created a new sheet and pasted my other content from the other doc there, copied the rules from the other sheet and pasted the rules into the second sheet; deleted the first sheet which was the copy of the other document with the formatting rules I need), changed the name and voila!

Comment: Thanks a lot Pnuts. It worked! Copied the document with the conditional formatting rules, created a new sheet and pasted my other content from the other doc there, copied the rules from the other sheet and pasted the rules into the second sheet; deleted the first sheet which was the copy of the other document with the formatting rules I need), changed the name and voila! Thanks a lot for your answer, it s been very helpful, I appreciate it. Romain